# how to get ID from URL in asp.net MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to get the ID from URL in ASP.NET MVC Controller and insert it into Project_ID, the below is my code, I tried but it's not working for me.

`http://localhost:20487/ProjectComponent/Index/1`

My Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveComponent(OrderVM O, int id)
{        
    bool status = false;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (Entities db = new Entities())
        {
            ProjComponent ProjComponent = new ProjComponent { project_id = id, title = O.title, description = O.description };
            foreach (var i in O.ProjComponentActivities)
            {
                ProjComponent.ProjComponentActivity.Add(i);
            }
            db.ProjComponents.Add(ProjComponent);
            db.SaveChanges();
            status = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method is a POST, not a GET (you cannot navigate to a POST method). And the url navigates to the `Index()` method of `ProjectComponentController`, not to a method named `SaveComponent`

Comment: When I wear blue pants my car wont start.

Comment: dear Stephen Muecke, thanks for your comments, yes you are right i did a mistake on that. and i did not clearly described my problem. for details  i posted many data through ajax in my controller accept project_id which is needed to be store in other table as foreign key.  so how I can get the ID  in my controller which uses Post Method from View in ASP.NET MVC??

Comment: What method do you want to send ProjectID Ajax or From submit ??????

Comment: I want to use Ajax

Comment: JQuery Ajax or AJAX helper ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a hidden field and update it by jquery/javscript and send it to back end in ajax helper.....

Make sure 1.name should be exactly name as ActionMethod param and 3.Jquery ,jQuery Validate and jQuery unobstrusive ajax is loaded correctly

My code .cshtml

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<div>
    @{
        AjaxOptions options = new AjaxOptions();
        options.HttpMethod = "POST";
        options.OnBegin = "OnBeginRequest";
        options.OnSuccess = "OnSuccessRequest";
        options.OnComplete = "OnCompleteRequest";
        options.OnFailure = "OnFailureRequest";
        //  options.Confirm = "Do you want to Add Country ?";
        options.UpdateTargetId = "divResponse";
        options.InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter;
    }
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AjaxSend", "Stackoverflow", options))
    {

        <input type="hidden" name="project_id" id="project_id" value="project_id" />
        <input type="submit" value="Click me" />

    }
</div>
<div id="divResponse">
</div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var url = window.location.href;
        var array = url.split('/');

        var lastsegment = array[array.length - 1];
        console.log(lastsegment);
        $('#project_id').val(lastsegment);

    });
    function OnBeginRequest() {
        console.log('On Begin');


    }
    function OnCompleteRequest() {
        console.log('On Completed');
    }
    function OnSuccessRequest() {
        console.log('On Success');

    }
    function OnFailureRequest() {
        console.log('On Failure');
    }
</script>
```

and Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AjaxSend(String project_id)
    {
        //rest goes here
        return Json(new { Success = true });
    }
```

this link may help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36678257/asp-net-mvc-jquery-post-error/36678471#36678471)

Answer (score 2):

you can get the id from URL Like This:

Cotroller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    ViewBag.ID = id;
    Your Code......
    return View(...);
}
```

View:

```
@{  
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
var ID = ViewBag.ID;
```

}
Now you have an ID in the variable